# Centering text to A4 landscape dynamically using textmerg and tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, landscape, paper-size

I want to generate multiple tags with different codes on A4 (210mm x 297mm) paper. The idea is to cut the A4 in half *horizontally* in order to get two wide tags (297mm x 105mm). Therefore, cutting guides (in grey) at both sides in the center would be very useful.

What I want to achieve is something like below:

[image]

In order to generate multiple PDFs with the required codes, `textmerg` package was used in this MWE just to do that by retrieving the codes from a `jobname.dat` file.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{textmerg}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial Black}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}

\Fields{\onecode\twocode} 

\Merge{jobname.dat}{
  \begin{landscape}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \centering
\topskip4em \resizebox{!}{0.12\textwidth}{\noindent\onecode} \\ \vspace{6cm} \resizebox{!}{0.12\textwidth}{\noindent\twocode}\\
    \cleardoublepage%    
  \end{landscape}
}
\end{document}
```

**jobname.dat**

```
DDD-GG-XX
DDD-UU-DD-XX
DDD-GG-XX
DDD-PP-VV-XX
```

The output is not centered and there are no cutting guides. My question, is how can I achieve the following using tikz:

- two codes per page, each one is centered inside its page
- ability to scale the text
- drawing centered grey cutting guides to cut A4 paper into equal halves.
- making use of the A4 paper in a landscape position leaving a reasonable amount of margin space for an obvious aesthetic reason.

Comment: Have you looked at the flowfram package?

Comment: no, could you provide a solution using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This creates two frames per page, each `.8\paperwidth` wide and 4cm high.  To remove the edges, use `\newflowframe` instead of `\newflowframe*`.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=60pt,landscape,oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{textmerg}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial Black}
\usepackage{flowfram}

\newlength{\pagebottom}
\pagebottom=\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\textheight-\paperheight\relax
\newlength{\pageedge}
\pageedge=\dimexpr -1in-\oddsidemargin\relax

\newflowframe*{.8\paperwidth}{4cm}{\dimexpr\pageedge+.1\paperwidth}{\dimexpr\pagebottom+.75\paperheight-2cm}
\newflowframe*{.8\paperwidth}{4cm}{\dimexpr\pageedge+.1\paperwidth}{\dimexpr\pagebottom+.25\paperheight-2cm}

\pagestyle{empty}
\Fields{\code}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\Merge{jobname.dat}{\parbox[c][4cm][c]{\linewidth}{\centering\code}\newpage}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

Revised solution:  These fill the whole page and use about as large a font as will fit.

Note, one could do the same thing using just the `\parbox`es if you could figure out how to set the margins to 0 with KOMA.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=100pt,landscape,oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{textmerg}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial Black}
\usepackage{flowfram}

\newlength{\pagebottom}
\pagebottom=\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\textheight-\paperheight\relax
\newlength{\pageedge}
\pageedge=\dimexpr -1in-\oddsidemargin\relax

\newflowframe{\paperwidth}{.5\paperheight}{\pageedge}{\dimexpr\pagebottom+.5\paperheight}
\newflowframe{\paperwidth}{.5\paperheight}{\pageedge}{\pagebottom}

\pagestyle{empty}
\Fields{\code}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\Merge{jobname.dat}{\parbox[c][.5\paperheight][c]{\linewidth}{\centering\code}\newpage}
\end{document}
```

---

This solution uses TikZ.  (It needs to run twice.)

```
\documentclass[fontsize=100pt,landscape,oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{textmerg}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial Black}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pagestyle{empty}
\Fields{\codeone \codetwo}
\begin{document}
\Merge{jobname.dat}{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.center)!.5!(current page.north)$) {\codeone};
\node[inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.center)!.5!(current page.south)$) {\codetwo};
\end{tikzpicture}
\newpage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, could you scale up the text to fill up more space while leaving only a small margin at all sides? However, I cannot accept it as an answer because no tikz code was included.

Comment: You scale it with the [fontsize=...] option.  Why do you want tikz code?

Comment: tikz is good for scalability, using the `positioning` library, one can *snap* whatever text in future to the desired coordinates. This gives more control to position your text.

Comment: Using TikZ scale does not affect the font size.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,landscape,nohead,nofoot]{geometry} %option: use `showframe` key to show the frame
\usepackage{textmerg}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}           % scalebox
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial Black}

\begin{document}
\Fields{\onecode\twocode} 
\Merge{jobname.dat}{
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[][0.5\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \scalebox{9}[12]{\onecode} % tweak the {x}[y] values
  \end{minipage}
  \textcolor{gray!10!white}{\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}} % cutting guide
  \begin{minipage}[][0.5\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \scalebox{9}[12]{\twocode}  
  \end{minipage}
  \cleardoublepage%    
}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I don't see this as an answer for there is not `tikz` code inside, but it has less complex code than the other solution. The guides would be better if they were on the periphery of the paper not in the middle, which obviously I couldn't do here. I like what the `\scalebox` can do to fine tune the size of the text.